# Is it possible to set different edgecolors for left and right edge of matplotlib bar plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.7

I would like to set different edgecolors for the different edges of a bar plot, plotted with matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar. Does anyone know how to do this? For example: black edges for right edge but no edges/edgecolor for upper, lower and left edges.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bars of a bar plot are of type [`matplotlib.patches.Rectangle`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html) which can only have one `facecolor` and only one `edgecolor`.  If you want one side to have another color, you can loop through the generated bars and draw a separate line over the desired edge.

The example code below implements the right side draw in a thick black line. As a separate line doesn't join perfectly with the rectangle, the code also draws the left and upper side with the same color as the bar.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bars = ax.bar(np.arange(10), np.random.randint(2, 50, 10), color='turquoise')
for bar in bars:
    x, y = bar.get_xy()
    w, h = bar.get_width(), bar.get_height()
    ax.plot([x, x], [y, y + h], color=bar.get_facecolor(), lw=4)
    ax.plot([x, x + w], [y + h, y + h], color=bar.get_facecolor(), lw=4)
    ax.plot([x + w, x + w], [y, y + h], color='black', lw=4)
ax.margins(x=0.02)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: If the bars were created in another way (or example using Seaborn), you can investigate the `containers` of the `ax`. `ax.containers` is a list of `containers`; a `container` is a grouping of individual graphic objects, usually rectangles.  There can be multiple containers, for example in a stacked bar plot.

```py
for container in ax.containers:
    for bar in container:
        if type(bar) == 'matplotlib.patches.Rectangle':
            x, y = bar.get_xy()
            w, h = bar.get_width(), bar.get_height()
            ax.plot([x + w, x + w], [y, y + h], color='black')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It explains it very well. But I am wondering, how would I get x,y,w,h from the bar Container I dont know or find anything about get_height,get_width, get_xy() functions that can be applied to a bar container? Maybe the problem is I am using mpl.axes.Axes.bar rather than plt.bar?

Comment: `plt.bar()` just calls `mpl.axes.Axes.bar()` for the "current" ax. I updated the code to work with `ax` (which is the recommended way, `plt.bar()` can get confusing when there are multiple subplots). I added some explanation is case you can't save the result of `ax.bar` into a variable (such as `bars` in the example).

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect! I managed to create the edges as expected.